# Space vs. Grid : when to use which?

Tags: reactjs, antd

Ant-Design recently added the [Space](https://ant.design/components/space/) component to its core. It automatically puts space between components by wrapping them into divs with margins. I'm struggling to find a clear rule of thumb as to when to use `Space` vs. `Grid`, as both seem to address the same challenges. There are some differences :

- `Space` is by default `inline-flex`, thus not taking up the whole width by default ;
- One can't set a percentage size for `Space`'s children.

But I'm struggling in one of my projects to see a clear reason to use one instead of the other in some cases.

Is there a simple rule of thumb ? Thank you.